# Фига и... фига

Tags: этимология

Вот, подумалось: а что было раньше: фига в значении "кукиш" или фига — вкусный фрукт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фрукт, разумеется, раньше. Кукиш назвали по сходству с внешним видом.

Answer (score 0):

Кукиш ещё называют дулей (диалектное название груши)